# Form of acceleration for motion in an ellipse

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, orbital-motion, acceleration, celestial-mechanics

I came across the following question:

> The coordinates of a particle moving in a plane are given by $x(t)=a\cos(pt)$ and $y(t)=b\sin(pt)$, where $a>b$ and $a$ and $b$ are positive constants of appropriate dimensions.

This is not the question being asked but what condition should the acceleration(given by differentiating $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ twice with respect to time $t$) satisfy for us to state that it's always directed towards the focus of the ellipse $x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2$ that the particle traces?

Comment: Have you tried differentiating to find the components of acceleration, $a_x=\ddot x$ and $a_y=\ddot y$?

Comment: Yes, I have; ax= -p²acos(pt) and ay= p²bsinpt. How to proceed with this information, to show that acceleration always points toward the focus of the ellipse traced by the particle? Also, why did u downvote this question?

Comment: I down-voted because you have not shown effort to solve your own problem. See the [site policy for such exercises](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) ... Elliptical motion results from a central force (ie directed towards a point) of the form $F=ma=k/r^2$. The components ($a_x, a_y$) give you the direction of the acceleration $a$ at the point ($x, y$). Can you use the geometry of the ellipse to show that $a$ points towards one focus? And is proportional to $1/r^2$ where $r$ is distance from that focus?

Comment: Technically, mine isn't a homework question since it was related to a concept and not exactly specific to this problem alone. Furthermore, I'm sorry that I didn't include the values of acceleration that I had found by differentiating in the question itself; I will keep this in mind when posting questions in the future. I was(and still am) confused about how to attempt to prove that a given acceleration vector **always** points toward a certain point. Can u please explain some more?

Comment: Oh crap, the acceleration comes out to be ax=-p²(acospt) and at=-p²(bsinpt). Both are negative. My bad, sorry.

Comment: Sorry, Kaumudi - just realised that I am misleading you, because in these equations $t$ is a general parameter which may not be *time*. So the components of acceleration are not necessarily $\frac{d^2 x}{dt^2}$ etc. I suggested an approach without checking first that it worked - my apologies... What you are trying to do, I think, is what Newton did : given that planets move in elliptical orbits and sweep out equal areas in equal times, what is the law of force between them? See [this document](http://www.math.utk.edu/~freire/m231f07/m231f07NewtonKeplerConverse.pdf) for one method.

Answer (score 0):

Note sure if I understand your question, but I'll try to give an answer. The acceleration is proportional to the force thanks to $\mathbf{F}=m\mathbf{a}$. So if the acceleration point to the center (focus of the ellipse}, then it is because the force points to the center. The force can (under certain conditions) be derived from a potential $\mathbf{F}=-\nabla \phi$. So if the force points to the center, then the associated potential is symmetric around the center and it increases as one moves away from the center.

Comment: Can u please explain the second equation in ur answer? I'm afraid that I'm not aware of it(I only just graduated high school).

Comment: Actually, after differentiating, the acceleration vector can be written in terms of the position vector as a=-p²r, where r is the position vector r=xi+yj. This means that for every point on the ellipse, the acceleration points in fact, toward the origin; am I correct in assuming that?

Comment: Potentials are things one learns about, when you learn about Hamiltonians and stuff. That stuff is quite a mouth full. If you are interested in that you can try to find some introductory text on classical mechanics. I love your enthusiasm.

Comment: @KaumudiHarikumar : Yes, you are correct. If $t$ is time then the acceleration vector is directed towards the *centre* of the ellipse, not one *focus.*  The law of force in this case is $F=ma= -mp^2r$.